# How do I put two doubledecker plots together?

Tags: r, graph

Im doing an exercise about a survey on university student´s satisfaction and I have to do a double decker on satisfaction 1 or 0 by the gender, course, univ, and fathers job.

I have decided to split the exercise is two graphs, one for male and other for female. This is the coding so far:

```
library(vcd)
C4_1<- filter(C3,Sexo == "Male")
C4_2<- filter(C3,Sexo == "Female")

a4 <- doubledecker(satisfaccion ~ Asignatura + Profesión_padre + Centro, data = C4_1,gp = gpar(fill = c("orange", "blue")),spacing=spacing_equal(0))
b4 <- doubledecker(satisfaccion ~ Asignatura + Profesión_padre + Centro, data = C4_2,gp = gpar(fill = c("orange", "blue")),spacing=spacing_equal(0))
```

Now I want this two graphics to join into one. I have tried with grid.arrange(a4,b4) but this error shows up:

```
Error in gList(list(0L, 3L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 4L, 2L,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
Además: Warning messages:
1: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Realizando coercion de LHD a una lista
2: In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Realizando coercion de LHD a una lista
```

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: i have updated the post with the library that double decker is from

Answer (score 0):

You can combine plots with the `par()` function. The option `mfrow=c(nrows,ncols)` lets you specify if you want the two plots in one or two rows.

In your case, I suppose this should work:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
doubledecker(satisfaccion ~ Asignatura + Profesión_padre + Centro, data = C4_1,gp = gpar(fill = c("orange", "blue")),spacing=spacing_equal(0))
doubledecker(satisfaccion ~ Asignatura + Profesión_padre + Centro, data = C4_2,gp = gpar(fill = c("orange", "blue")),spacing=spacing_equal(0))
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I put what you told me and it doesnt merge the two graphs toguether :(